# MySQL not working with virtualhost

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, virtualhost

I'm working locally on my Macbook Pro using XAMPP and I'm trying to setup virtualhosts so that I can work on multiple projects more easily.

Everything appears to be working fine except I can't connect to MySQL through PHPMyAdmin and on the XAMPP control panel it says MySQL isn't running. However, I can access MySQL through an application I have in my htdocs folder. When I access phpmyadmin through localhost/phpmyadmin the CSS is loaded and PHPMyAdmin appears to be located, but MySQL can't connect so I'm not quite sure where the issue lies (considering I can connect through my application)

Upon going to localhost/phpmyadmin I get the following error

```
#2002 - No such file or directory
The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).
```

The thing is, I can access the database just fine through the application. I can log in, save and do any other sort of interactions with the database.

Here's what I have in my httpd-vhosts.conf file

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test1"
    ServerName localhost

    <Directory /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test1>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName pma
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/phpmyadmin"

    <Directory /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/phpmyadmin>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        <IfModule mod_php5.c>
            AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
            php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
            php_flag track_vars On 
            php_flag register_globals Off 
            php_value include_path . 
        </IfModule> 
    </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

**Now for a summary**

1. I set up virtualhosts for apache on my Macbook
2. The virtualhost setup appears to be working fine for the application I have in my htodcs folder, and it can connect to the database. I can log in, save data and all that stuff.
3. When I browse to localhost/phpmyadmin I get a MySQL connection error. If I browse to pma/phpmyadmin (the virtualhost I tried to create) Chrome and Firefox just search google for it instead of recognizing the alias (is that the correct term?)

Comment: Does `localhost:80/phpmyadmin` work?

Comment: did you check if php's configured to use the right socket path/filename?

Comment: @TiesonT. No, when I enter that it just changes/redirects to localhost/phpmyadmin

Comment: @MarcB I'm not sure what it should be set to. Are you referring to php.ini? If so, what should I be looking for?

Comment: it should be the same as whatever mysql's been configured to use. you'd have to check the mysql my.ini/my.cnf file to find that out.

Comment: I didn't change the socket or path for it. It only started behaving like this when I enabled virtualhosts.Do I have to create a virtualhost for port 3306?

Comment: no. apache virtualhosts have absolutely NOTHING to do with mysql.

Comment: Just curious, why did you ask me to check? It was working prior to adding virtualhosts and I haven't touched anything MySQL related.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same thing with a WAMP server.  I solved it by putting back the original "out of the box" server settings:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/Apache2/docs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

And then for each project used code such as:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/projectname"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias projectname.here
    <Directory "C:/wamp/projectname">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all # <-- used for Apache 2.2
       #Require all granted  #<-- used for Apache 2.4+
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

For different projects, just duplicate the last set of code for each project, renaming the DocumentRoot, ServerAlias and Directory path.  You will notice the "`ServerAlias`" line; this is what made Apache serve up the project when entering the alias in the web browser.  I found the explanation [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/) which ironically was in the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file.

Also, please note that my research recommends for higher versions of Apache to use `Require all granted` in place of `Allow from all` as commented in the code above.

All of this code is in the httpd-vhosts.conf file, which on my Windows 7 installation is at `c:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.21\conf\extra` directory.  Since you are using a Macbook and have already identified the location, I just put this in for other's reference.